# In Flutter, how to upload a file to a PubNub channel?

Tags: flutter, dart, pubnub

I need to send a file to a channel but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

First I select the file
then I do,

```
Uint8List fileContent = await f.readAsBytes();
await pubnub.files.sendFile(channelId, 'smiley.jpg', fileContent );
```

But I get an error saying
PubNubException: request failed (HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable).

Any idea on how to send the file in PubNub?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using [the latest Pubnub Dart/Flutter SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-now-supports-flutter-2-0-with-our-newest-sdk/)